# Google App Engine, links going to the index page

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I saw one other post about this and didn't find a solution. Basically all the links on my web app are going to the main index page (home.php). I have my app.yaml file like this:

```
application: csmain
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /css/*
  static_dir: css
- url: /images/*
  static_dir: images
- url: /jquery/*
  static_dir: jquery
- url: /downloads/*
  static_dir: downloads
- url: /classes/*
  static_dir: classes
- url: /lib/*
  static_dir: lib
- url: /.*
  script: home.php
```

On the source the links comes out as `<a href="login.php"> Login </a>`

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
- url: /
  script: main.php 

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```